# Regarding Candidate Keys and Superkeys

Tags: sql, primary-key, tuples

I have a quick question regarding candidate keys and superkeys. Say you have two keys (a, b) where 'a' is a primary key and b is a candidate key. Would the combination of these two keys be a superkey ie. would (a,b) be a superkey? Or would it be a candidate key. My assumption is that it would be a superkey because the definition of a candidate key states that it is a irreducible superkey and the combination of the two fields a and b could be reduced to either a or b. Is this logic correct? Or am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Because a and b are keys, a + some attribute or b + some attribute are a superkeys. Then a + b is also superkey.

Comment: But the superkey itself would not be considered a candidate key because its not minimal, correct?

Comment: @BenNelson Candidate keys are always superkeys, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the combination of these two keys be a superkey ie. would (a,b) be a superkey?

Yes, it would still uniquely identify rows.

> Or would it be a candidate key.

No, it would no longer be minimal.

> My assumption is that it would be a superkey because the definition of a candidate key states that it is a irreducible superkey and the combination of the two fields a and b could be reduced to either a or b. Is this logic correct?

Almost. Yes it would be a superkey, but not because it can be reduced. It would be a superkey because it is unique.

Every candidate key is superkey, but not every superkey is candidate key. So `{a}` is both candidate and superkey, `{b}` is both candidate and superkey and `{a, b}` is just superkey.